# Cost sensitive analysis versus Threshold

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, python, precision-recall, sensitivity-specificity

I am running a cost sensitive ensemble methods (for the first time to access algorithms of this type) 'CostSensitiveRandomPatchesClassifier' in Python on my imbalanced dataset (positive cases are rare and counted for 0.5% of the total).

What I found are:

- I set the cost matrix element in the order: [Cost_FP,Cost_FN,Cost_TP,Cost_TN]. Set both Cost_TP and Cost_TN to zero. Then I adjust the cost value for Cost_FP and Cost_FN, I can find the AUC as well as recall, precision and thus f1 score are varying. E.g. I change the cost matrix [1,11,0,0] to [3,11,0,0].
- Unfortunately I found the AUC was deteriorated while introducing the cost matrix, according to my practice so far. Meanwhile the impact of the cost matrix on the f1 score is quite similar as the probabilistic threshold.
- The model performance seemed to interact with the relative cost between Cost_FP and Cost_FN rather than the absolute number. e.g. A pair of Cost_FP=1 and Cost_FN=10 act the same with Cost_FP=100 and Cost_FN=1000.

**For example:**

Under a non-cost-sensitive algorithm, I got a model performance as shown:[image]

Quite good AUC and recall but low precision and thus f1. This is highly probably due to the imbalance target.

The confusion matrix can provide a more strait forward view on the performance:[image]

So my goal to introduce the cost sensitive method is to prompt f1 score especially precision while keep a reasonably high AUC and recall.

But when I change the setting of the cost matrix, I can also find the same move path in both recall and precision: i.e. if precision was promoted by a new setting of the cost matrix, the recall will also be harmed somehow. This is what the threshold do likewise.

So what I can find is the cost sensitive did not act better (actually act poorer) than the threshold in my case.

Could anyone please advise if I missed something in applying this methods or any other more effective way I can raise my f1 score up?

Many thanks

Comment: I think resample the minor class or subsample the major class will help. BTW, your output graph is very beautiful, what tool or lib do you use to draw it?

Comment: @qiuyuan It's data robot, a non-open-source machine learning software.